# How do we deal with a recurring question like OS install base statistics?

Tags: discussion, best-practices

In the `[iphone]` tag, there's a commonly recurring question about install base statistics for the various OS versions out there.  While developers can use this information to determine what capabilities to support in their next application, install base statistics vary day-to-day.

This would seem to make such questions too localized to a moment in time, thus there can't be definitive answers to them.  However, few if any of these questions get closed and they just pile up.  Most even get voted up, because other developers are interested in these statistics.

For example:

- [What percentage of iPhone users have the different versions of iPhone OS/firmware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021929/what-percentage-of-iphone-users-have-the-different-versions-of-iphone-os-firmware)
- [iPhone installed base upgrade rate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659911/iphone-installed-base-upgrade-rate)
- [What iPhone OS to target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131133/what-iphone-os-to-target)
- [Is it worth only supporting the iOS 4 when making an iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216953/is-it-worth-only-supporting-the-ios-4-when-making-an-iphone-app)
- [iPhone/iPod Touch Version Statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074033/iphone-ipod-touch-version-statistics)
- [Anyone have statistics on iOS adoption rate and iPhone upgrade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778863/anyone-have-statistics-on-ios-adoption-rate-and-iphone-upgrade)
- [What percentage of iPhone users using each iOS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650648/what-percentage-of-iphone-users-using-each-ios-version)
- [is it still worth to support ios 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813983/is-it-still-worth-to-support-ios-3-1)
- [iphone ios4 stats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312581/iphone-ios4-stats)

and today:

- [Percentage users still on iOS 3.x? Should I bother?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502839/percentage-users-still-on-ios-3-x-should-i-bother)

In fact, several of the askers know that these questions have been asked before, but they re-ask them because they feel the responses to the older questions are no longer valid.

Voting to close as too localized or as duplicates seems ineffective, as I'm often the only vote.  Should I not care about these questions being asked over and over again, because other developers find them interesting?

Comment: These really should all be closed as too localized or duplicates; it's pretty amazing they've all lasted this long. I voted to close them all.

Comment: You seem to have had an effect, @Mark! Several of those questions are now closed. Since your close votes expired long ago, I mod-flagged one of the still-open ones and included this MSO post in the description.

Comment: @Popular Demand - Yes, it appears the solution is to complain about it on Meta.  Unfortunately, it is a recurring problem and at least one new question has appeared since I listed these that asks the same thing.  Mod flags may be the way to go on this.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly direct them to post their question on the [Apple site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), but as Mark points out in his comment they really are too localised.

No direct migration as the site's still in beta (as I write) and it's unlikely to have one set up as all four migration slots from SO will soon be filled (hopefully with a route to Programmers).