# Not sure where to ask; question was closed

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I'm developing a web app and a requirement is that it work on popular android devices. I've seen android development questions asked on android.stackexchange and have been closed since that board is not about development. So I posted my question on stackoverflow instead - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443019/where-to-find-current-android-screen-size-stats

I am trying to get the most recent data I can in order to make an informed decision on building for that device or not. Since this is for development, the marketing and PR stuff doesn't help me at all. The numbers on the android developer site are a good start, they're just old for this one specific metric (the rest are updated every couple weeks.)

Knowing that data is key to development. I imagine that's why it, as well as related stats, are on the main android developer site. There are third party sites that provide their own stats for iOS, so I imagine (but have not found) similar third-party tracking is done for android too.

How can I make that question more about development? Or, where else should I have posted it? It seems like this is the sort of data developers need to know, and it's really only relavant to developers.

Comment: It would help if your question was a *programming* one.  One way you could make it a programming question is by showing the code that you wrote that requires these stats... it's entirely possible that the user community can tell you a way to do it without needing the stats at all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I still see this as entirely a business decision, not a programming one.  By stats it appears he means number of units sold, not the dimensions of the screen.  The number of units sold is not of direct impact on any concrete programming problem.

Comment: @Servy: Hence, my "reality test" of showing the code that these stats are to be written against.  It's a red herring; the stats are probably not used in the actual code, but only used to make decisions about which code to write or not to write, making the question squarely off-topic.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8005/how-large-is-the-average-screen-size-for-an-android-phone (outdated), http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15688/list-of-devices-with-screen-parameters, related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3422/will-the-android-os-support-higher-resolution-screens

Comment: I would think this would qualify as: "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession". I don't care about sales figures. I understand they're not a of direct impact on development. I need to know what percentage of android devices currently in use are large and hppi/hdpi. That has direct impact on dev. Those ^^ links are too subjective for what I'm looking for. I need to decide, for example, which breakpoints and pixel densities I should build for. If large hppi now accounts for 10% of the market, I need to build for it. If it's 2%, I can ignore it for now.

Comment: And it's not that there is code that requires these stats, the stats are required to determine if I should write the code or not. Ie, we're not building for Windows Mobile because its marketshare is far too low. Determining which breakpoints and screen densities to build for sure seems like "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession".

Comment: A larger problem with device statistics is how rapidly any answers to a question like this go out of date. One recurring question in [ios] is about whether or not to support older iOS versions, so people have asked for current install base statistics. However, those stats go out of date soon after the question is asked, [prompting people to keep re-asking the same question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72954/how-do-we-deal-with-a-recurring-question-like-os-install-base-statistics). This is one of the reasons why we have a "too localized" close reason.

Comment: Unless you can find a definitive source that has these statistics and never goes out of date (like [Google's Android stats](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)), you'll have even more of a problem here, considering how quickly the Android landscape changes every month.

Comment: @user1337: For the record, I've lobbied to get the phrase, "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" removed for this very reason.  For a question to be on-topic, it must **also** be about: *a specific programming problem,
a software algorithm, or
software tools commonly used by programmers.*

Comment: @BradLarson there are a couple sites for iOS that are continually updated, but run by third parties. My hope was to find that sort of thing for android.

Thanks to all for helping me see why this would be considered off-topic. I'm still not sure where this should have been posted, however, since I've seen lessor development related questions closed on android(dot) for being too development related.

Comment: @user1337: I think Brad's point is that your post would have to be constantly updated to be useful.

Comment: @RobertHarvey and my point is if the answer links to a site that is continually updated, then my post wouldn't have to be updated. Eg, if the answer was something like http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/ or http://www.14oranges.com/blog/

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a search engine.

Comment: I'm not saying StackOverflow is a search engine... I'm not sure what you mean by that comment. It's a place for developers to ask development related questions and get answers.

Comment: Yes, but it's not a place where you can [ask for links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: There's many thousands of answers where the answer ends up being a link. And I see nothing in the FAQ about not providing links. Often the best answer to something is a resource. And let's face, as far as answers go, many development related questions are not current forever, and thus would need to be continually updated to be useful for an extended period of time. Code gets deprecated all the time.

Comment: The link I provided in my comment above is a [meta-faq entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).  You can argue with me all you like, but I'm telling you the truth.  Links go bad, information gets outdated.  And the information you are asking for becomes outdated five minutes after it is posted, making it [Too Localized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized).

Comment: It's a _community_faq_entry_... not in the  meta faq http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq . But more importantly, it's not in the main StackOverFlow FAQ - the one we're asked to look at before posting. And you can cite a thread on meta about being Too Localized - but it's not anywhere in the sections about what to post and what not to post. All you have been able to do is cite information that is outside of the posting guidelines as defined on StackOverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: The FAQ is not a comprehensive resource.

Comment: It does spell out the basics of what should be posted and what shouldn't be. It doesn't cite meta for additional info on what should and should not be posted. It doesn't mention the meta community faq. And none of the reasons for why you think my question wasn't good, align with what is in the main FAQ.

Try using the FAQ on the main site to support your claims. You may wish that it's more comprehensive, but that's just your opinion (and it may be supported by others.) And while you've lobbied to get that phrase removed, the fact remains it's still there and it bears far more weight than meta.

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow exists to give the community a voice, and some influence over how the site is run.  The fact is, questions that are too localized and requests for links are both issues that have been discussed extensively on Meta, and community consensus on those issues has already been established.  If you don't like that consensus, well, that's just tough luck I guess.

Comment: Except that what you consider "consensus" conflicts with what the main site says. Then people close topics that are in compliance with the rules. What you're saying is, you don't care what the rules are, if you can get enough people to violate them and enforce your own rules on users who are abiding by the rules, that's a good thing and "tough luck" to those who follow the rules.

Comment: `It doesn't cite meta for additional info on what should and should not be posted` -- that's how things have been done for all eternity, though. Think of Meta as the common law of Stack Overflow. You have a point in that maybe the FAQ should state that more clearly.

Comment: @user1337: If you look at [the bottom of the faq for the main site](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#what-about), you will see that it [links to the FAQ entries on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq).  They are officially supported.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that reference is in different context, and outside of the context of what should and shouldn't be posted.

Comment: @Pekka, that could very well be the case and I'm not arguing against that. What I'm saying is, it's not clear and nor have I agreed to having my content moderated in that way. There's no warranty, so no recourse. But still, it's just bad policy to list one set of rules and then allow people to ignore them and enforce a different set, without telling users that's what goes on.

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  Despite your persistent protests, I'm telling you the truth.  You can argue all you like, but there it is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it means you're not following the rules as written. Even above you note that you dispute the rules. As per the rules I've agreed to by using this site, I haven't violated any in my post and it didn't justify being closed. What you're saying is, based on other rules that I didn't agree to, it should be closed. Your reference to the bottom of the FAQ is in a different context. Not sure what you don't understand about that.

Comment: It means you're trying to re-interpret the rules to satisfy your own sensibilities, that's what it means.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what you're doing, you're the one that wrote "For the record, I've lobbied to get the phrase, "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" removed for this very reason." You can't tell me my question should be closed based on the main FAQ and what it says should and should not be posted.

Comment: There isn't any way we could possibly shoehorn all of the community consensus into the FAQ; it would be the size of the Gideon Bible, and no one would read it.

Answer (score 4):

Questions that will become invalid in a short time are typically closed as "[Too Localized.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized)"

Questions asking for links to external resources are [off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: That's what meta says, but what the main site says is questions that are "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" are okay. There is nothing official, nor that I agreed to when signing up, saying that "too localized" is not allowed. And I didn't ask for links to external resources, I simply said that would be a suitable answer. I don't have the answer, that's why I asked a question. Nice try, but again I cite the official rules.

Comment: @user the official rules are a rough guideline for people to vote by, nothing more. The rest is guided by community consensus, which is sometimes reflected by Meta discussion. "Shopping list" questions (including requests for external resources) have been off topic by that consensus - pretty unequivocally - for a long, long time now. You can choose to ignore that consensus but that won't get you very far.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Note that I didn't request external resources, I simply said I would be okay if the answer included one. That happens here all the time. Secondly, nothing in the actual rules of the site say that external resources are against the rules. I get that many here don't follow the actual rules, and that may be the SOP, but still, that's not apparent to the users nor is it something they agree to when they post.